# What is the best way to save Java Enums using Firebase

Tags: java, firebase

I'm using Google's Firebase. I placed a Java Enum as one of the members in one of my model classes. When an instance is saved to the Firebase Database it throws an exception. What is the best way to resolve?

Comment: I don't know Firebase specifically, but generally the preferred approach when using a text-based database (such as JSON/Mongo) is to use the enum names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After additional research. Here is a workaround for Firebase 3.0.0. Apparently previous versions Firebase had more flexible support for Jackson that has been eliminated. Here's a Job class with enum that works (with the hacky code)

```
public class Job {
  public enum JobLifecycle  {
    New, inTransit, inStorage, delivered, signedOff;
  }

  ...// other fields omitted
  JobLifecycle lifecycle;

  public Job(){
  }


  @Exclude
  public JobLifecycle getLifecycleAsEnum(){
    return lifecycle;
  }

  // these methods are just a Firebase 9.0.0 hack to handle the enum
  public String getLifecycle(){
    if (lifecycle == null){
      return null;
    } else {
      return lifecycle.name();
    }
  }

  public void setLifecycle(String lifecycleString){
    if (lifecycleString == null){
      lifecycle = null;
    } else {
      this.lifecycle = JobLifecycle.valueOf(lifecycleString);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me, but it's workaround, is there any solution ?

Comment: I think this is still the best way in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Found a partial answer to my question but still looking for a workaround.

If one defines the enum and model class like that shown below, then suddenly enums get persisted successfully as a 2 node structure with the typename as the parent and the string value of the enum as child. BUT when I attempt to read such as node with code like `Job j = xxx.getValue(Job.class)` an exception will be thrown: `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.ranchosoftware.ranchomovingandstorage.model.JobLifecycle is missing a constructor.` Based on comments by Frank, I don't think there is a solution to this in Firebase right now. I'm not sure what is the best workaround.

```
public enum JobLifecycle  {
  New, inTransit, inStorage, delivered, signedOff;

  JobLifecycle(){}

  String value;

  @JsonValue
  public String getValue(){
    return this.name();
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static JobLifecycle fromValue(String jobLifecycleString){
    for (JobLifecycle l : JobLifecycle.values()){
      if (l.name().equals(jobLifecycleString)){
        return l;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid jobLifecycle code: " + jobLifecycleString);
  }
}
```

Use it like this in the model class:

```
public class Job {
  ... // other fields omitted
  JobLifecycle lifecycle;

  public Job(){
  }

  ... // other content omitted

  @JsonProperty("lifecycle")
  public JobLifecycle getLifecycle(){
    return lifecycle;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that you found a solution. Can you add some code that shows how you use the class in your code? It'd also be great if you could specify what version of Firebase you are using, because since the latest release (Google Play Services 9.0) the `JsonProperty` annotation is not included anymore.

Comment: I'm using Firebase 9.0.0 along with google play services 9.0.0. I don't have lots of experience using Firebase yet, adding the @Jsonxxx annotations just worked. Without the annotations and extra code the saving throws an exception. I may figure out more about "why" this works in the next  couple of days and I will update.

Comment: In the 9.0.0 release we don't have a replacement for `@JsonProperty()` yet. But we'll be adding one in an upcoming release, so that you can remove the Jackson dependency from your app and reduce your APK size.